# Hosting WCF in IIS with (Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, impersonation

I have a WCF service (MyService.svc) that im hosting under IIS 7.5.
My .svc is under the same virtual directory as the Web App itself.
I am trying to get some of my service operations to require user impersonation:

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
```

I have used basicHttpBinding with:

```
 <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
      <transport clientCredentialType="Ntlm"/>
 </security>
```

After publishing this, i go to http:///MyService.svc.
This is when i get the following error:

```
The contract operation 'HelloWorld' requires Windows identity for automatic impersonation. A Windows identity that represents the caller is not provided by binding ('BasicHttpBinding','http://tempuri.org/') for contract ('IMyService','http://MyService'.
```

*** Update / Fix ***
I found my issue. I was not providing the namespace component of my service name in the web.config. This was making the whole thing barf.

```
 <services>
      <service name="**MyNamespace**.MyService" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior">
         ...
      </service>
 </services>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, it sounds like you didn't provide credentials when you created the proxy?  I haven't done impersonation in WCF, but I'd recommend looking at providing credentials (either via the config file or programatically at proxy creation).